# System.Web.HttpContext.Current get lost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I developed an MVC 5 app.

Inside a controller, I have this action:

```
    // POST: Usuario/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(UsuarioViewModel model)
    {
        //
        // some tasks
        //
        //
        return Json("Some text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When that action is called after a html form submit, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is not null. I am using that object somewhere in the code.

Now, I need to call this same action method from other action method in the same controller. In that case, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null, causing obviously, the application to throw a null object exception.

The action method and the call are:

```
    // POST: Usuario/CreateFromStaff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CreateFromStaff(int[] trabajadores)
    {
        //
        // some tasks
        //
        //
        UsuarioViewModel model = new UsuarioViewModel();
        //
        // model properties assignments
        //
        //
        JsonResult json = Task.Run(async () => await Edit(model)).Result;  // When this call is made, the Http context get lost.
    }
```

What can I do so that the http context is kept? or, how can I do that call?

**Question Edit:**

Just to be clearer. The `Edit` action method is the standard way to store a record, in this case a user record. At some point in this action method I have:

```
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

On the other hand, the `JsonResult json = Task.Run(async () => await Edit(model)).Result;` is inside a `ForEach` method. After that loop, I need to save other data, so that I am using another `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` after it.

If I configure the ForEach method as `async` I have always problems with the second `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`. An error is thrown telling that some database operations are incomplete. That is why I used `.Result` and the `ForEach` method not to be `async`.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Why are you using `HttpContext.Current` in an MVC app? You really should try to avoid doing that to begin with. Secondly don't use .Result on a Task instance, that is asking for runtime deadlocks. Use async/await all the way in your call stack. Also async/await will capture the synchronization context which includes `HttpContext.Current` assuming you are not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` with a lower .net runtime version than 4.6.

Comment: If you need access to the HttpContext you can register and inject HttpContextBase in your types using a IoC / DI framework. Really though I would just avoid using it all together if possible.

Comment: I need `HttpContext.Current` because inside a helper class I need to get which controller was called for auditing tasks. That helper class is outside a controller so I need to get the context that way. I am using `.Result` because that async methods are inside a ForEach loop. After that loop I have `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`. Since inside the `Edit` method are another `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` call, I always have problems. Maybe that problem is for other question. At this time, I need to solve the problem of the http context.

Comment: @Igor besides the other comment of mine, I editted the question to explain why I needed to use `.Result`. And you are right, I am not using `ConfigureAwait` at all.... so that by default, it is `ConfigureAwait(true)`

Comment: @Igor If I need to know the controller that was called for auditing purposes from other class outside a controller, how can I do it? At this moment, the only way I know to do that is by mean of the HttpContext.

Comment: `I need HttpContext.Current because inside a helper class I need to get which controller was called for auditing tasks.` ← A more generic solution would be to use an Action Attribute (global or at the action level) that captures this information in some instance at the Request level that you can then inject in other instances that need it. That way you capture it at the beginning of the request and pass in the abstracted values (like maybe Http Verb or Controller name or whatever you need) and those types do not have to deal with an HttpContext which reduces coupling and makes for easier testi

Comment: @Igor Thanks, but I have done the suggestions made in the answer and now the context is not null, so that the controller and action names were retrieved correctly inside the helper class. Apparently the Task.Run call was the problem. And in order to not have problems with the async method, I changed `ForEach` extension method by a simple `foreach` instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can I do so that the http context is kept? or, how can I do that call?

Remove the `Task.Run` call. You should [strongly avoid ever using `Task.Run` on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

> the `JsonResult json = Task.Run(async () => await Edit(model)).Result;` is inside a `ForEach` method... If I configure the `ForEach` method as `async`... An error is thrown telling that some database operations are incomplete. That is why I used `.Result` and the `ForEach` method not to be async.

Indeed, the `ForEach` method does not properly understand `async` lambdas, and if you make its lambda `async`, then you will end up with `async void` lambdas, which [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). That would [cause the "asynchronous operation incomplete" errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#respect-the-safety-nets).

I assume the fix went something like this:

1. `ForEach` doesn't work with `async`, so I need to make it synchronous.
2. [Blocking didn't work](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), so I need to use `Task.Run` to avoid the deadlock.
3. Well, now I don't get `HttpContext.Current`. How can I get `HttpContext.Current`?

But a better fix is this:

1. `ForEach` doesn't work with `async`, so I need to use something other than `ForEach`.

Changing `ForEach` to `foreach` will solve your problem in a much nicer way.